# Dojo charting. X-axis labels not sequential order

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, line

I have a chart where the X-axis pulls data from a cell in an SQL table. The source data cell for the SQL table is formatted as DATE. The SQL cell is formatted DATETIME. When the data is exported to a .csv the cell format is again DATE and a chart built in the .csv has the X-axis in sequential date order. When the same data is viewed in a chart on our GIS the X-axis dates are out of order making the plotted data impossible to decipher. Here is the code for the chart. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

function makeChart(featureset) {

```
dojo.empty("chartDiv");

var dlg = dijit.byId('chartDialog');

// When resources are loaded and the DOM is ready....
dojo.ready(function () {
    var data = featureset._jsonData.items;
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            identifier: "TestID",
            label: "Parameter",
            items: data
        }
    });

    chart = new dojox.charting.DataChart("chartDiv", {
        comparative: true
        //scroll:stretchToFit
    });
    chart.setStore(store, { Parameter: '*' }, "Result");
    //chart.addAxis("x", {title: "Sample#", titleOrientation: "away", majorLabels:true, minorTicks:true, minorLabels:true,
            if (data.length > 2) {
        chart.addAxis("x", {
            title: "Collection Date",
            titleOrientation: "away",
            majorTicks: false,
            majorLabels: true,
            majorTickStep: 5,
            minorTicks: false,
            from: 0, to: (data.length + 0.5),
            labelFunc: function (n) {
                // I am assuming that your timestamp needs to be multiplied by 1000. 
                //var date = new Date(parseInt(data[n].CollectionDate) * 1000);
                var date = data[n].CollectionDate;
                return date;


            }
        });
    }
    chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true });

    var c = dojo.connect(chart, "onData", function () {
        dojo.disconnect(c);
        if (dijit.byId("chartlegend")) {
            dijit.byId("chartlegend").destroy();
            dojo.create("div", { id: "chartlegend" }, "chLegHd");
            chlegend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({ chart: chart }, "chartlegend");
        }
        else {
            chlegend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({ chart: chart }, "chartlegend");
            chlegend.startup();
        }
    });
});

dlg.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I changed the source cell from datatype "datetime" to "date" and that made no difference in how the chart displays. It should show sequential dates i.e. 6/14/2015   7/01/2015   8/13/2015

but it is displaying thusly 8/13/2015   7/01/2015   6/14/2015

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure I understood your question very clearly. You want to display the date in sequential order retrieved from the DB. Here is what you can do:

You can create the labels array by the data base data retrieved.

```
var dBDateArray= ["array of dates from the DB in sequential order"];
var labelsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dBDateArray.length; i++,) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.value = i;
    obj.text = dbDateArray[i].name;
    labelsArray.push(obj);
}
```

Set the labels in `x` Axis to `this.labelsArray`

```
this.chart1.addAxis("x", {
title: "Collection Date",
titleOrientation: "away",
labels:labelsArray
})
```